# How to call certain procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Disclaimer: it has been a long day so I hope this makes sense!

I'm using MSSQL 2008R2 and create billing files for a few vendors, each of which has their own billing rules.

I either run billing for all vendors or just a single record, something simplified like this:

```
insert into billing
select xyz from table where billtype = A and (record = @rec or @rec = 0)
union all
select abc from table where billtype = B and (record = @rec or @rec = 0)
union all
select mno from table where billtype = C and (record = @rec or @rec = 0)
etc
```

If I pass it a single @rec then it just runs that one or if I pass @rec=0 then it runs all of them.

I realize this has way more overhead than it needs to. I would like to be able to run a master procedure (spBillAll?) similar to how I do it now and then have that call the appropriate sub-procedure (spBillVendorA, spBillVendorB, etc) for the single record or all records.

Actually if all the billing logic is split up into individual procedures for each vendor then I could just call one master spBillAll or a single spBillOneRec as needed. I suppose spBillAll would loop through all records and pass them through to each spBillVendorA/B/etc as necessary.

I may be thinking about this in totally the wrong way but I appreciate any feedback/suggestions!

Cheers.

Comment: "I realize this has way more overhead than it needs to" - measure performance and identify bottlenecks first. The query from the question looks OK to me as is. I'd add only `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to it.

Comment: you can create one sql function(with parameter-vendorid) which returns the particular vendor record; then create one Store procedure and call the function for each vendor.You must use the loop to call the sql function.  And Finally join all records and return it.